# Jquery show hide not working properly on large screens. and not at all working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am using show and hide to slide up and down my menu items on mouse click. 
I have 2 issues in it.
Apparently they are working fine. But when i did some serious testing by clicking every parent list item again and again i found that they have click issue , sometimes they  expand and sometimes **it takes two clicks to work.**
This is my first problem.

Second problem is that they are **not working on mobile devices at all**.

Here is a fiddle
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsy8ywor/)

Html

```
<div class="mega-col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" data-type="menu">
<div class="mega-col-inner">
    <ul>
        <li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="menu-title">Massachusetts Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <div class="dropdown-mega level2">
                <div class="dropdown-menu-inner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu">
                            <div class="mega-col-inner">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=24"><span class="menu-title">Burlington Mall, MA</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=25"><span class="menu-title">Burlington Mall, MA - Cart</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="menu-title">New Jersey Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <div class="dropdown-mega level2">
                <div class="dropdown-menu-inner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu">
                            <div class="mega-col-inner">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=26"><span class="menu-title">Brunswick Square Mall, NJ</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=30"><span class="menu-title">Garden State Plaza, NJ</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=27"><span class="menu-title">Menlo Park Mall, NJ</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=29"><span class="menu-title">Ocean County Mall, NJ</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class=" "><a href=""><span class="menu-title">Rockaway Townsquare, NJ</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="menu-title">New York Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <div class="dropdown-mega level2">
                <div class="dropdown-menu-inner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu">
                            <div class="mega-col-inner">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=31"><span class="menu-title">Galleria at White Plains, NY</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=42"><span class="menu-title">Manhattan, NY-Toys 'R' Us </span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="parent dropdown-submenu mega-group"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="menu-title">North Carolina Stores</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <div class="dropdown-mega level2">
                <div class="dropdown-menu-inner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 mega-col" data-colwidth="12" data-type="menu">
                            <div class="mega-col-inner">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=32"><span class="menu-title">CrabTree Valley, NC</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class=" "><a href="index.php?route=common/location_details&amp;loc_id=2"><span class="menu-title">Fayetteville, NC</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $("li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a").on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass('active');
$('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide();
if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.dropdown-mega.level2').show();
});
```

Css

```
li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group .dropdown-mega.level2 {
display: none;
}
li
 {
padding:10px;
position: relative;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: use ionic framework. that's a great framework to build hybrid apps

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira How can i fix my current issue

Comment: i think its about delay on click. every html component have 300ms delay on android every click because android need to know if user want to scroll page or click the item

Comment: I've tried your fiddle on 3 different mobile browsers and it worked, could you be more specific?
The other problem is because you have to remove class active from all other elements first

Comment: @Boris on my website this functionality is not achieved on mobile devices. here is the link to my website. please see locations menu to see this functionality. onhttps://ifixandrepair.com/finalUpGrade/ .. If i remove class first than a new issue arises that it will not hide the parent LI if i click it again. to see the issue click any parent LI twice it will show but it wont hide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$("li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a").on('click', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide();
    $('li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a').removeClass("active")
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.dropdown-mega.level2').show();
});
```

Comment: This code will be fix my two click issue but it will raise another issue that it will not hide the parent li if i click it again. to see the issue click any parent LI twice it will show but it wont hide.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to hide all dropdowns, then show actual dropdown

```
$("li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide();
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $("li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.parent').find('.dropdown-mega.level2').show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsy8ywor/5/)

and about that mobile issue

you have to move this

```
#li_menu169 li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group .dropdown-mega.level2 {
    display: none;
}
```

out of @media (min-width: 1200px), because this rule will apply only to screens bigger than 1200px. You probably want it to be applied to all screen sizes so your dropdown is hidden when website is loaded.
And there is probably some problem with event.preventDefault(); on mobile browser so I've edited my JSFiddle and added return false; to the end, it should do the trick

Comment: The 2 click issue has been resolved. its working fine. Please elaborate your answer. P.S. please help me so that it runs fine on mobile devices.

Comment: try to put "return false;" without quotes at the end of your jQuery function, it should prevent website from refreshing when menu item is clicked and check my edited answer

Comment: Boris the issue is fixed for large screens but on mobile i guess its reloading the page and its not working. i have applied the right CSS for display none in all screens. here is the link to my website https://ifixandrepair.com/finalUpGrade/  it is in locations menu. Please review.

Comment: i have this file included in my header for js (jquery-1.7.1.min.js)

Comment: I'm not sure where's the problem, your function is not running on small screens at all. Try to put this function out of $(document).ready( function(){});  
Functions in $(document).ready() are automatically started after page loads and you need your function to be started when user clicks menu item. But I'm not sure if this is causing the problem